# "syntax error on token ";" ,, expected" after private ... adapter

Tags: java, android

It writes syntax error on token ";" ,, expected after the line `private ArrayAdapter adapter ;`

```
package ru.for_listactivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

    final String[] catnames = new String[] { "Рыжик", "Барсик", "Мурзик",
    "Мурка", "Васьк", "Томасина", "Бобик", "Кристина", "Пушок",
    "Дымка", "Кузя", "Китти", "Барбос", "Масяня", "Симба" } ;

private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter ; // here is a problem

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catnames);

}
```

Comment: private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catnames);

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you have code outside of the methods, and not inside a static initializer block.

Try this:

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catnames);
```

Comment: i tried that already and just now. in this way the eclipse doesn't show a mistake but the app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine:

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter ;
```

It declares `adapter` so it can be used by any method contained in the class.

This however, is not:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catnames);
```

It needs to be inside a method (perhaps you want it in `onCreate`?), not just in the class: